# How can I push to an object property array based on a string match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to read a list of files and, based on character matching, push found values to a designated array within an object.

There is an object that has three property keys, each with an empty array as a value. I need to parse a list of files, each one, for two specific string values, compare one of the two values to the object property keys and, if a match, push the second value to that property value array.

I am stuck on how to connect the second found value with the correct property key based on the first value's match. The script currently pushes all of the second values to all three of the object property arrays, when I only want the second value pushed to the array that matches the first value found in the file.

Modules

```
fs
glob
```

Directory structure

```
+-- _parse-test.js
+-- _scss
|   +-- component.scss
|   +-- document.scss
|   +-- utilities.scss
```

Run program

```
node .\parse-test.js
```

parse-test.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var glob = require("glob");

function runProgram() { 

    var navObjects = {
        'Components': [],
        'Document': [],
        'Utilities': []
    }

    const files = glob.sync("scss/*.scss", "matchBase:true");

    files.forEach(async (file) => {

        try {

            const navPairings = { 
                component: "",
                parent: ""
            };

            let componentName = "";
            let navName = "";

            const text = fs.readFileSync(file).toString().split("\n");

            for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

                if (text[i].includes("/// @group") === true ) {

                    componentName = text[i].replace("/// @group ", "");
                    componentName = componentName.replace("\r", "");
                }

                if (text[i].includes("/// @navGroup") === true ) {

                    navName = text[i].replace("/// @navGroup ", "");
                    navName = navName.replace("\r", "");

                }

                navPairings[i] = {
                    component: componentName,
                    parent: navName
                }

                const pair = navPairings[i];

                for (let navGroup of Object.keys(navObjects)) {

                    if (pair.component !== '') {
                        if (navObjects.hasOwnProperty(navGroup)) {
                            navObjects[navGroup].push(pair.component);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }     
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log("Error", e.stack);
            console.log("Error", e.name);
            console.log("Error", e.message);
        }
    });

    console.log(navObjects);
}

runProgram();
```

SCSS file contents

component.scss

```
/// @group nav
/// @navGroup Components
```

document.scss

```
/// @group scroll
/// @navGroup Document
```

utilities.scss

```
/// @group colors
/// @navGroup Utilities
```

Current console output

```
{ Components: [ 'nav', 'nav', 'scroll', 'scroll', 'colors', 'colors' ],  
Document: [ 'nav', 'nav', 'scroll', 'scroll', 'colors', 'colors' ],
Utilities: [ 'nav', 'nav', 'scroll', 'scroll', 'colors', 'colors' ] }
```

Desired console output

```
{ Components: [ 'nav', ... ],  
Document: [ 'scroll', ... ],
Utilities: [ 'colors', ... ] }
```

How can I push the second found values to the correct array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're getting `navGroup` from `Object.keys(navObjects)`.
Then you're checking if `navObjects.hasOwnProperty(navGroup)`

I'd say that's pretty much always true. Don't you think?

You don't need that last for-loop at all. This should suffice:

```
                if (pair.component !== '') {
                    if (navObjects.hasOwnProperty(pair.parent)) {
                        navObjects[pair.parent].push(pair.component);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: I hate it when I overthink. You da best! ++++